# UISearchBar segue in CoreData using didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, core-data, uisearchbar, segue, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a Core Data project set up as a **Master-Detail VC**. I've added a `UISearchBar` to it which works properly. What's monopolized an amount of time I'm embarrassed to admit (it's BAD) is getting it to properly show the details when I click on the cell.

I had been trying to use `prepareForSegue`, but my instructor suggested I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` instead to segue to the `DetailVC`.

Here's what I've tried to do:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedNote: Note

    // Check to see which table view cell was selected.
    if tableView == self.tableView {
        selectedNote = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Note
    } else {
        selectedNote = self.searchController.filteredObjects[indexPath.row]            
    }

    // Set up the detail view controller to show.
    let detailViewController = DetailViewController()

    // Note: Should not be necessary but current iOS 8.0 bug requires it.
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!, animated: false)

    navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
}
```

With the code above, the compiler says `'UISearchController' does not have a member named 'filteredObjects'`

I'm baffled, as I've got that set up already in at the top of the `MasterViewController` class.

Here's the setup info:

```
class MasterViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var detailViewController: DetailViewController? = nil
    var addNoteViewController:AddNoteViewController? = nil
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

    // Added variable for UISearchController
    var searchController: UISearchController!
    var searchPredicate: NSPredicate?
    var filteredObjects : [Note]? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        if let split = self.splitViewController {
            let controllers = split.viewControllers
            let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
            let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity!
            self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
        }

        // UISearchController setup
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController?.searchBar
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.definesPresentationContext = false
    }
```

Here are the UISearchBar methods:

```
// MARK: - UISearchResultsUpdating Delegate Method
// Called when the search bar's text or scope has changed or when the search bar becomes first responder.
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    let searchText = self.searchController?.searchBar.text // steve put breakpoint
    println(searchController.searchBar.text)
    if let searchText = searchText {

        // This sets up the seachPredicate and filteredObjects array
        searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "noteBody contains[c] %@ OR noteTitle contains[c] %@", searchText, searchText)
        filteredObjects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects?.filter() {
            return self.searchPredicate!.evaluateWithObject($0)
            } as! [Note]?

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        println(searchPredicate)
    }
}

// MARK: - UISearchBar Delegate methods

func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    updateSearchResultsForSearchController(self.searchController)
}

// This resets searchPredicate & filteredObjects when the SearchController is dismissed
func didDismissSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    println("didDismissSearchController")
    self.searchPredicate = nil
    self.filteredObjects = nil
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the feeling when you stare on your code so long that you miss obvious:

```
selectedNote = self.searchController.filteredObjects[indexPath.row]
```

Should be

```
if let filteredObjects = filteredObjects {
    selectedNote = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]
}
```

As you have `filteredObjects` declared as instance variable of your `MasterViewController`

Comment: Compiler now says: `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Note]?' with an index of type 'Int'`.

Comment: Edited my answer - you need to unwrap optional first. Also, preffered style for swift is to reference instance variables without `self` unless neccessary

Comment: Thank you so much! Onto the next problem: Getting the `DetailVC` to show the stuff that `prepareForSegue` was previously doing.

Comment: Good luck in your endeavors! ;)

Comment: Before I run down the answer, am I correct to assume this replaces `prepareForSegue` or do I need to keep what I've got there?

Comment: Yes, this should remove the need for having segue attached to cell.

Comment: However, if you have `DetailVC` designed in storyboard - which I assume you do if were using segues - you should instantiate it from storyboard, i.e. replace `DetailVC()` with `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier_assigned_in_IB")`

Comment: where `identifier_assigned_in_IB` is?

Comment: It is string you specify for ViewController in InterfaceBuilder > Identity Inspector tab > Storyboard ID field